# Drupal 7 - How to get AJAX response displayed in a ctools modal?

Tags: ajax, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I want to create a ctools modal popup when a button is pressed.

```
function custom_form( $form, &form_state ) {
  $form['btn'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('add'),
    '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'custom_callback',
    ),
  );
}

function custom_callback() {
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');

  ctools_modal_render( 'Error', 'Error Message');
}
```

I only get the alert message with the un-rendered ajax response. How can get I this response displayed in rendered format in modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Documentation on: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/7
or: http://drupal.org/node/1635198#comment-6120546 on how to render drupal messages.

For more Information about ctools modal you may check: [Example to display webforms (webform.module) within CTools modal windows](http://drupal.org/node/1196150)

Or what about a tutorial like: "[Ajax modal windows, the easy way](http://zroger.com/2009/12/ajax-modal-windows.html)"

Comment: I checked with all those links prior to posting my question.For the example in the last tutorial modal window is invoked via text link in which the ctools-in-modal class is added to the attributes.

I need to know a method, by using which I can add same attribute to ajax button.

Comment: Maybe it's an option to just theme the link as a button.