# Problems rendering drupal 7 user registration form with ajax in BootStrap 3 Modal

Tags: ajax, forms, javascript

I have a subtheme based on bootstrap 3 and am trying to load user registration form(user_register_form) on front--page.tpl.php, I am adding #ajax to the submit button using form_alter

```
     $form["actions"]["submit"] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'wrapper' => "user-register-form", "effect" => "fade",
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'callback' => 'my_form_submit_handler',
            'method' => 'replace',
        ),
        '#value' => t("Sign-up"),
        '#id' => 'user_register_form'
    );
```

I am rendering the form in two places on the same page (a) in a div which is a regular div 
and (b) in a bootstrap modal div as mentioned here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
     <?php
            if (user_is_anonymous()) {
                $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
                 print drupal_render($form);
            }
     ?>
```

in case (a) the ajaxified form works very well, however in case (b) the form is no longer ajaxified , the submit button does not have the "ajax-processed" class attached.

I intend to open all my application forms using bootstrap modal and ajax however i am not able to do this as of now.
I want to know the right way to load any ajax form in bootstrap modal dialog 
I know this is a fairly common problem with modal dialogs and drupal forms, but i am yet to understand what the reason behind this behaviour, any help or direction will be highly appreciated.

There is one more similar question that is unanswered here 
[Drupal load form with ajax callback in Bootstrap modal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98223/drupal-load-form-with-ajax-callback-in-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By rendering the user registration form twice, duplicate form id's were being created. After recreating the second form with a different ID, things are good.