# How to keep modal open after form submission?

Tags: ajax, forms, theming

I use Bootstrap theme for D7 site. On a front page I have a simple form which can be filled by anonymous user. When user submits form he is forced to register to move forward. I saved `$form_state['values']` into `$_SESSION` to use them later and added some attributes to `Submit` button

```
'#attributes' => array(
    'data-toggle'=> 'modal',
    'data-target'=> "#register-modal",
    'data-backdrop'=>"static",
),
```

But form submission forces page reload and closes modal window. `'data-backdrop'=>"static"` attribute doesn't work in this case. Is there any chance to submit form without page reload (i'm not an expert in AJAX) and keep modal opened?

Comment: If you are using webform, you can try [Webform Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax)

Comment: Example here might help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112763/problems-rendering-drupal-7-user-registration-form-with-ajax-in-bootstrap-3-moda