# Location map in colorbox

Tags: javascript

I am using **'Location map module'** and I have made a block of it displaying my required map.
My requirement is to view that map in colorbox when some user clicks on **'Map'** link.

I need to use Location map module only. I tried to achieve above using views but didn't worked.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this module [Colorbox Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) which allowed me to view **Location Map Block** in colorbox.

Follow this simple steps (to show only map block).

- Enable **Colorbox Node** module. (Make sure colorbox module is already installed)
- Create a Basic page and render Location Map Block in content region.
- In this page display only **Location Map Block**.
- Create a **Global:Custom text** or any custom link and add below code as a
  text in it.

  `<a class="colorbox-node" href="/your-path?width=600&height=600">Map</a>`

By this you can render any block which you want to.

[image]